# Exit console without waiting press any key to continue...

Tags: c#, console-application

I want to quit my Console Application, I have tried following commands:

```
Enviroment.Exit(0);
Application.Exit();
```

But it leads to `Press any key to continue . . .`. How could I exit my application without waiting any key?

Comment: Attach your debugger man . It must have an expection

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This only appears when you're running it from within Visual Studio itself, but only when running it without attaching a debugger (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> in most cases). Try actually running the built .exe in your Bin folder and observe the behavior of your application that way.

Comment: Thanks, that made the trick. This didn't even come to my mind :)

Comment: @Taurib Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped you out :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a demo console application:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

The app exits without any such warning.

Comment: It's by design, when you're going through an exit path when running the app from within Visual Studio without attaching a debugger, for it to prompt you. If you attach a debugger or run the .exe, it won't show the prompt.

Comment: i ran it from bin directory, it didnt showed any such warning. vs2013

Comment: That's exactly what I said. Only when you run it from within VS, without attaching a debugger will it prompt.